# Puppeteer test runs are not consistent

Tags: puppeteer

I've made some tests using Jest and Puppeteer, but some of them pass/fail inconsistently. From what I've found, all of the tests pass **consistently** when `{headless: false}`, and I can see Puppeteer interacting with Chromium. But once I set `{headless: true}`, a few of them pass/fail whenever. It's always the same few tests that inconsistently pass, too. For the tests that inconsistently pass, the reasoning is always `< element > not found`. This is one of the test cases that inconsistently passes, with the reasoning `#gallery not found`.

```
describe('Gallery', () => {
  it('opens gallery modal', async () => {
    const mediaSelector = 'div#media';
    const gallerySelector = '#gallery';
    await page.$eval(mediaSelector, (e) => {
      e.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
    });
    await page.click(mediaSelector);
    await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
    await expect(page).toMatchElement(gallerySelector);
  });
)};
```

I've made sure to precede every expect statement with `await page.waitForTimeout(1000);` to give the element enough time to display in the HTML. I had heard that the behavior is different for Puppeteer when its headless/headful, but I didn't think it would affect this type of test that much since it's a fairly straightforward test. Any suggestions on how I can overcome the different behavior between headless/headful Puppeteer?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the code that's under test. There's not much to say other than `waitForTimeout` is very brittle and causes a race condition. There's likely a better way to wait for something to appear, probably `waitForSelector`, `waitForFuntion` or even spinning on an `evaluate` that's testing an arbitrary predicate, but all of this is dependent on the code under test to really say much more.

Comment: The code I presented was the code that was being tested, but is it not a minimal reproducible example because I didn't include await page.goto(...)? Sorry for not including that, I thought that may have been implied. Thanks for letting me know about `waitForTimout`, I've gone through and applied `waitForSelector`s before anything that requires an element, and they're all passing consistently now.

Comment: I may not have been clear -- the code under test is an app of some sort with HTML and JS that has selectors like `'div#media'` and `'#gallery'`. If the tests are failing, there's no telling what the cause is without seeing the app under test. Maybe these selectors don't exist or there's a typo, or some JS script randomly removes the elements 1 in 1000 times or any number of other possible scenarios -- it's anyone's guess. Glad the `waitForSelector` approach worked for you -- consider adding a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you feel confident in your solution.